# How do you follow an animated object without using the camera?

Tags: path, bezier-curves

I am animating a project where an object moves along a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and rotates at different points of the curve. I'm having trouble with figuring out how to follow that object on the path, so I can rotate it accordingly.

I don't want to use the camera, because I don't want to animate in camera mode. The solution that I'm working with is to press <kbd>Num</kbd> every once in a while which is super annoying.

Answer (score 7):

Under the <kbd>n</kbd> menu "View" tab there is an option for "Lock to Object"
[image: The n menu]

Comment: Thank you so much. This saved me so much time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Lock To Active View".
This will lock your view to the object you've locked onto.

To enable it, press "**shift** + **numpad .**"

Your keyboard shortcuts may vary, so you can look it up under

edit -> preferences -> keybind -> Lock to active view

Comment: What is "Shift numpad"? Is it Shift + the key labelled *"Num"* on the numeric keypad? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe it's *[Shift]* + *[Numpad Dot]*? But in Blender 2.9, searching for *Lock to Active View* by F3 gives me no matches. The command *View > Align View > View Lock to Active* has no shortcut by default, and *[Shift]* + *[Numpad Dot]* is not assigned.  But *View > Align View > View Lock to Active* does what is described in the answer with the screenshot *(Lock Object to [Cube])*

Comment: you need to search for that in the keybinds, as ive mentioned there, whoever edited it, edited it incorrectly